# Exception @ org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$ViewMetadataHandler.createLocation() When JSF project is converted from Ant to Maven

Tags: java, maven, jsf

Recently we have started converting a JSF project from Ant to Maven. When we deploy it JBoss we are getting NullPointerException.
Following is the stacktrace.

```
null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$ViewMetadataHandler.createLocation(SAXCompiler.java:331) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$ViewMetadataHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:458) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parseStartTag(CShaniSaxParser.java:1368) [shani-parser-1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3.jar:]
at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parseSTARTTag(CXmlParser.java:1398) [shani-parser-1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3.jar:]
at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parse(CXmlParser.java:948) [shani-parser-1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3.jar:]
at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parse(CShaniSaxParser.java:767) [shani-parser-1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3.jar:]
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompileViewMetadata(SAXCompiler.java:815) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compileViewMetadata(Compiler.java:97) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:414) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:57) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:131) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:128) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:113) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:50) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:509) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:493) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2584) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.access$000(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:147) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage$FaceletViewMetadata.createMetadataView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2738) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:243) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143) [myfaces-impl-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198) [myfaces-api-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at com.dstoutput.plc.faces.support.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:63) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
```

Below is our pom.xml
As when it was with Ant we don't have version number for some of the jars. So, we tried with nearby version based on the other dependent jars.

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.dozer/dozer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> 
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId> 
        <version>16.0</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-b73</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jdom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xom</groupId>
                <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jtidy/jtidy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
        <version>r938</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.odysseus.juel/juel-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.odysseus.juel/juel-spi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-spi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--         
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl 
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
    plugin.org.allcolor.shanidom</groupId>
        <artifactId>shani-xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>

    </dependency>
     <!--        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
  plugin.org.allcolor.shanidom</groupId>
          <artifactId>shani-xml-apis</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop 
   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
 beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
 context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
 context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
   core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
  expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans - 
  ->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.maven-play- 
    plugin.org.allcolor.yahp/yahp-internal -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
    plugin.org.allcolor.yahp</groupId>
        <artifactId>yahp-internal</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
          plugin.net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>   
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
             plugin.org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
                <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play- 
       plugin.org.allcolor.yahp</groupId>
        <artifactId>yahp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>start</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Please let me know if any other information is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the stacktrace shows a specific non-standard XML parser is included which is in your pom and most likely plays a role here... Check that...

Comment: Agreed but which jar we are not very sure. we tried excluding several jars but that lead to some other exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but neither JSF, nor Java (the jdk) nor maven is responsible for this or an actual part of the cause of the problem.